# how to open application on specific monitor

Tags: .net, windows-8.1, automated-tests

I have multiple monitors and doing automated testing(with testcomplete) on my application.
Need to open application in particulate monitor.
Testcomplete doesn't support for that but said

```
dotNET.System_Windows_Forms.Screen
```

... would help.
But I see no such object available. I'm on Windows 8.1 and dotNet 4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363374/showing-a-windows-form-on-a-secondary-monitor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13742259/62576

Comment: MaxQueue- no use I'm a tester using a application hence not able to change application/windows properties Ken- could not see { dotNet.System.Windows }  object withing testcompleate IDE